# Does specifying a mixed distribution imply the associated probabilities?

Tags: bayesian

For example,

if we are told that we have a prior on $\tau$

and that the distribution of $\tau \sim \frac{1}{2}I(\tau=1/2)+\frac{1}{2}Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$

Is this equivelent to saying that

$\tau$ has the distribution of $I(\tau=1/2)+Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$
and  has the distribution of $Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Or is that $\tau$ has $I(\tau=\frac{1}{2})$ with $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and $Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ with $p=\frac{1}{2}$.  In the second case, it would assure they are proper, but I do not know if that is a requirment.
That is, is it implied from the first formulation of the prior? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second thing would be the intent.

While you could definitely regard it as just a kind of shorthand, it can also be seen as intended somewhat more formally if you regard it as specifying the cdf in terms of component cdfs, since the cdf of a mixture with mixing weights $\mathbf{w}$ is the weighted average of the cdfs with the same mixing weights.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated the question a little bit, as I had it before wouldnt that possibly imply the distribution would integrate to more then one?

Comment: Sorry, it's the second thing in your current question; which integrates to exactly 1. Each component on its own has probability 1, which each get multiplied by $\frac12$, making the total 1.